# SQL Server - altering column default value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to alter a default value for a column in an existing table.

I assumed (and I actually found a few examples on the net "confirming" this) that I could do 
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column SET DEFAULT 'something' but I get syntax error and according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx DEFAULT is not supported.

Next idea was to drop the default constraint from the database but I found that when the table was created the constraint was not named and SQL generates a random name with every deployment so I can't reference it by name.

I came up with a query from sys tables that returns the name of the constraint:

```
select o.name from sys.objects o 
join sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.default_object_id
join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name='TableName' and c.name='ColumnWithDefValue'
```

I'm about to write a query by string concatenation and I can't stop thinking about how there must be a better way to do all this. Any suggestions?

TL;DR version: what's the easiest way to alter a default constraint for a column in SQL Server R2?

Thanks

Comment: The link you copied is a link to SQL Compact version, I'm using full SQL. The error I'm getting is Syntax Error at SET (or DEFAULT if I omit the SET keyword)

Comment: I hit this too once upon a time (which is why I always name my constraints). I did what your're doing, pull out the system-generated name, build dynamic code to drop it, then recreate it with a standardized name (I use DF_TableName__ColumnName).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to drop the constraint and then recreate it

http://bypsoft.blogspot.com/2007/10/changing-default-column-values-sql.html

Comment: Right, I've seen that but the problem is I don't know the name of the constraint so I can't drop it so easily.

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM sys.default_constraints
    WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName')

Comment: @msmucher0527: that query returns all default constraints on the table I still need to limit it per column, but thanks, that's one less join in my query...

Comment: are you trying to automate this?

Comment: Yes, it needs to run on multiple machines (multiple dev machines, qa, production...) and the names are different on most of those.